# Python and XHR Response

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I need to visit a web page and then click on a link. That link sends an XHR request and the server sends an XHR response. I need to capture that response and parse it. I used Firebug to view the XHR request and response but I need that response using Python.

I am trying to do it with selenium but can't find anything in selenium docs nor on google.

There are multiple similar questions here on stackoverflow but either they are answered regarding javascript or have no answer at all.

Comment: Can't you issue the request using a python library like [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: Is the format of the response, JSON, XML, html or plain text?

Comment: XHR requests are nothing other than "normal" HTTP-requests, nothing stops you from using the module mgilson mentions to reproduce the query, and pull out the results.

Comment: @mgilson I appreciate your help very much. I have constructed aa html header with help from Firebug and now its working fine!

Comment: @kums The response is JSON